# Apache Tomcat Password?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I'm using dsBudget to manage my budgeting software.
It's an apache tomcat web app.

Would anyone know how I can password protect it? Basically it is designed to work on a local machine, but I want to access it from multiple locations (which i can, but its not passworded)

Would anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about the password of Apache Tomcat or dsBudget?

Comment: Basically dsbudget is a tomcat webapp, so i need to password protect that.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat can be configured to password protect the contents of a web app.  [Here is a tutorial](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html) about setting it up.

1. Create *tomcat-users.xml* similar to this:

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <tomcat-users>
     <role rolename="tomcat"/>
     <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
     <user username="myname" password="mypassword" roles="tomcat"/>
     <user username="test" password="test"/>
   </tomcat-users>
   ```
2. Configure the *web.xml* for the web app to use the basic authentication by adding the following into the `<web-app>` section:

   ```
   <login-config>
       <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
   </login-config>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work.